# Problems with jquery and a special selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Friends,
I have a problem, now I want to access an element with jquery li,  unfortunately these li elements have the ids as follows:

```
<li id='abc-2\textbox'>...</li>
<li id='xop-2\listbox'>...</li>
```

I tried to get the item by the following expressions, but none work.

```
$('#abc-2\textbox') 
$('#abc-2\\textbox')
$('#abc-2//\textbox')
$('#abc-2\\\textbox')
```

I guess the problem is the \ character, Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('#abc-2\\\\textbox') (use 4 slashes)

Comment: In my first test this works very well, I'll do some further testing and will notify you

Comment: Your reply was most helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [HTML 4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter [A-Za-z] and may be followed by
>   any number of letters, digits [0-9],
>   hyphens "-", underscores "_", colons
>   ":", and periods ".".

Again that means alpha-numeric with the addition of hyphens, underscores, colons and periods.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not help me, these IDs are generated by a process that I do not control

Comment: @tecnocrata ... jQuery is not designed to handle invalid HTML.  Yeah it might work. but will it continuously be supported is another story.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an illegal character for the id.  [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp).

If there's another way to construct your selection (is the location of the  `LI` predictably relative to another element with a valid ID?) -- that would be your best bet.